# Snap SVG work with elements in group, not with group

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I can't understand, how to manipulate elements in Snap, so now I'm manipulating with groups.
Now my two SVG files loaded to different SVGs and then animated by group. How to load them all to one group and animate each one with different animations?

```
var roulette = Snap("#roulette");
var ball = Snap("#ball");
var rouletteg = roulette.group();
var ballg = ball.group();

var rouletteload = Snap.load("svg/roulette.svg", function ( loadedFragment ) {
    rouletteg.append( loadedFragment );

    var bbox = rouletteg.getBBox(); //bounding box, get coords and centre
    var scale = 2.85;
    wheelAnimation(bbox.cx, bbox.cy, 3000, scale);
});

var ballload = Snap.load("svg/white.svg", function ( loadedFragment ) {
    ballg.append( loadedFragment );
    var bbox = ballg.getBBox(); //bounding box, get coords and centre
    var scale = 2.85;
    var off = 30;
    ballAnimation(300, bbox.cy + off, 3000, scale);
});

var i = 0;

function wheelAnimation(cx, cy, speed, scale){
    i++;
    rouletteg.attr({ transform: 'r0 ' + cx + ' ' + cy + " s" + scale + "," + scale + "," + cx + "," + cy }); //Reset + Scale setup
    rouletteg.stop(true).animate(
        { transform: "r360," + cx + ',' + cy + " s" + scale + "," + scale + "," + cx + "," + cy }, // Basic rotation around a point. No frills.
        speed, // Nice slow turning rays
        function(){
            wheelAnimation(cx,cy, speed, scale); // Repeat this animation so it appears infinite.
        }
    );
}
function ballAnimation(cx, cy, speed, scale){
cx = 500;
    ballg.attr({ transform: 'r0 ' + cx + ' ' + cy + " s" + scale + "," + scale + "," + cx + "," + cy }); //Reset + Scale setup
    ballg.stop(true).animate(
        { transform: "r360," + cx + ',' + cy + " s" + scale + "," + scale + "," + cx + "," + cy }, // Basic rotation around a point. No frills.
        speed, // Nice slow turning rays
        function(){
            ballAnimation(cx,cy, speed, scale); // Repeat this animation so it appears infinite.
        }
    );
}
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DE1dds8n3ULOLQRATnLY?p=preview)

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding the problem you are having here...if you don't directly have the object already in a variable...you can do something like Snap('#someElementId').animate({transform:'s2,2'},1000) or whatever ? or s.selectAll('.someClass').forEach(someFunc) etc. Maybe add a bit of further description what you need.

Comment: @Ian yes! I want to put all elements to one Snap group and then animate them with different animation. But when I'm load them to one group they're can't be reached by group.select();

Comment: Can you include the group.select() stuff ? Maybe a minimal example on a jsfiddle to highlight the problem ?

Comment: @ian updated Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/DE1dds8n3ULOLQRATnLY?p=preview
There are I'm trying to animate roulette in "rouletteg"

Comment: ok, you can't transform an 'svg' named element itself, you would need to put the svg element inside a group for example (or have a group directly inside the svg) and transform/animate that. so <svg><g id="Layer_1">... or <g id="Layer_1"><svg>....  (there must be at least one outer svg element for the svg, but then you can have nested g's and svg's etc)

Comment: @ian ok, thank you. So if I'll load two SVGs (Layer_1 and Layer_2) to one SVG element, how to animate each one with different animations?

Comment: have the outer SVG with 2 groups inside (or append them). Then append each loaded svg into the respective group. Then animate that group.

Comment: @ian it will be a right way to work with SVG or to load each one to different <svg> elements?

Comment: @Ian answer this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084908/a-right-way-to-work-with-svg