# A right way to work with <svg>

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, snap.svg

What is a right way to work with SVG if I have full scene in SVG file?

1. Split scene to many files (e.g. characters, cars, birds, clouds, etc) and then load them up to different  elements for each one.
2. Load whole scene to one  element and then animate groups inside scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you work. I would imagine that working with others, e.g animators etc, that they would often provide separate files. So it may work out easier that way. I don't think there's a right answer to this one though. If you load it in one go, at least you don't have to work out when various async loads have finished though.

Comment: Thank you. Easier to work with separated files, but it's not efficient